# Send mails over gmail

Tags: c#, wcf, gmail

I know there is a ton of questions and Answers about this and I did read allot but it seems all outdated.

So I have a mobile app that registers a use to a cloud service and then sends a welcome email to the user's email address.

The service part is done in C# WCF Witch also sends the mail

Below is the prototype function for testing for the mail:

```
static void SendMail()
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("gmail account", "App name");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("User email", "User account");
    const string fromPassword = "gmail password";
    const string subject = "test";
    const string body = "Hey now!!";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
        Timeout = 20000
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Sent");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

My code used all the things suggested by others. But I still get the error message

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
```

Comment: try adding ` { if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMail))
                return; }` .To your function. I m not sure but

Comment: No change I get the Error in the line 'smtp.Send(message);'

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mime;


namespace Invoice.WCFService
{
    public class EmailSenser
    {

        public static bool SendEmail(string toMail, Stream stream, string mailBody)
        {

            bool sent = false;

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(toMail);
            mail.Subject = "Invoice";
            //mail.Body = "Please, see attached file";
            mail.Body = mailBody;

            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, ct);
            ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;

            disposition.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".pdf";

            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            try
            {
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                sent = true;
            }
            catch (Exception sendEx)
            {
                System.Console.Write("Error: " + sendEx.Message.ToString());
                sent = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                //DBContext 
            }
            return sent;
        }
    }
}
```

It's my fully working code

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
    static void SendMail()
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("fromMail", "App name");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress("tomail","app");
        const string fromPassword = "passwrd";
        const string subject = "test";
        const string body = "Hey now!!";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
            Timeout = 20000,
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress))
        {
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: if I run that from the dev machine I get the same error as above

Comment: Is Date and Time of your dev machine is accurate and are you able to use gmail service from dev machine using browser? Just a try...

Comment: yes Time and date are correct and I am able to use the gmail

Comment: Can you try this from another dev machine? The code I have provided is working for me. You should also enable your application to communicate over firewall. Add an exception to windows firewall or try turning off Windows firewall for a while.

Comment: hmm disabled the firewall and still the same :S

Comment: Many corporate networks block ports other than 80. Could you check using telnet or other commandline utils if port-587 is open for you.

Comment: @Jester Are you able to use Email clients like Outlook or thunderbird with Gmail? This looks like a problem specific with the environment.